# How to pass a variable name and string constant as function parameters in R?

Tags: r

I am new to R and have a question.
In the function below, `myclusterTEST` and `price_tiers_new` are constants. This means every time this function is run, the variables created will always be called `myclusterTEST` and `price_tiers_new`.

Is there a way to pass these two variables as function parameters? This way, we can generalize the function to run for any variables.

```
MyFunction <- function(swindex,total) {
 swdist = as.dist(1/(swindex))
 fit1 <- hclust(swdist, method="ward.D") 
 **myclusterTEST** <- cutree(fit1, k=2) 

  data_clusterTEST <- data.frame(**myclusterTEST**)


  # Create a new column for rownames
  d <- data_clusterTEST
  names <- rownames(d)
  rownames(d) <- NULL
  new_data_cluster <- cbind(names,d)

  out_total <- merge(total,new_data_cluster, by.x=c("**price_tiers_new**"), by.y=c("names"))

  return(out_total) 
}
test=myFunction(swmat_clean,total)
```

Comment: You can check for `?substitute` or `?match.call`  or `?"..."`

Comment: Currently those two are objects used within the `MyFunction`, one generated inside it. Which other function do you want to pass them to?